# Will using 20% acidity vinegar to descale tankless water heater do damage?

Tags: plumbing

I just descaled my tankless water heater and realized after the fact that the vinegar I bought off of amazon was way more acidic (20%) than the food grade vinegar you're supposed to use. Any idea if this will do major damage to my water heater?

Comment: if so, it's already been done. It either fails early, or not.

Comment: Well it’s putting out hot water. Was mostly worried about potential long term damage to my pipes due to corrosion

Comment: Should be okay as long as you did leave it in more than necessary and rinsed well.

Comment: I believe, @crip659, you meant "did _not_ leave it in more than necessary"?

Comment: @FreeMan  Thank you, hate it when a important word disappears.